# Link to table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

How do I hyperlink to the a link in the table of contents? See the highlighted part below for example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents\label{toc}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{First}
\lipsum[1-50]

\section{Second}
\lipsum[1-50]


\chapter{Chapter Second}
\section{First}
\lipsum[1-50]

\section{Second}
\lipsum[1-50]


%%%
\section{Third}
\hyperref[??]{link} %%%%%% Link to Chapter 2.3 in Table of Contents 
%%%
\hyperref[toc]{ToC} %%%%% This is not enough as it links to the Table of Contents, not the particular link I want

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly do you want? Should the target of the link be that line in the ToC? Or are you asking how to create new links like the ones in the ToC? Or are you asking how to create another link that has the same target like the line in the ToC?

Comment: @Skillmon Basically, when I click on the link, it will take to that part of the ToC

Comment: I have no idea how robust this is, but you could use `\NewDocumentCommand\hyperintoc{mm}{\hypertarget{#1}{#2}}` in your preamble (just to have a robust alternative to `\hypertarget`), then use `\section[\hyperintoc{strangetarget}{Third}]{Third}` instead of just `\section{Third}`, and reference it with `\hyperlink{strangetarget}{link}`.